# Syntax in using the checked item in CheckListBox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create an if statement using a checklistbox. How can I make an if statement with my checked value in check list box? I tried using the code below just like in combobox:

```
If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems = "AHRM" Then
```

But I got an error:

> value of type cannot be converted to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CheckedListBox.CheckedItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) returns a [collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditemcollection(v=vs.90).aspx) of all checked items. Not a single string.

You could check it's `Count` property and then take the first if you expect only one:

```
Dim checked As String = Nothing
Dim checkedItems = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
If checkedItems.Count <> 0 Then checked = checkedItems(0).ToString()
If checked = "AHRM" Then ....
```

If you expect multiple you could use following little LINQ query and `Contains` or `String.Join`(if you want to concat them):

```
Dim checkedItems = From obj In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast(Of Object)()
                   Select checkedItemAsString = obj.ToString()
Dim containsAHRM As Boolean = checkedItems.Contains("AHRM")
Dim allChecked = String.Join(",", checkedItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dim values As [String] = ""

For i As Integer = 0 To CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1

If CheckBoxList1.Items(i).Selected Then

values = CheckBoxList1.Items(i).Value

```
   If values  = "AHRM" Then
   // your code
   end if
```

End If
Next